# Send 3 files to recipient using javamail within NetBeans 8.2 IDE developed program

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

The below code sends 1 attachment to a recipient. However, I need to send 3 files to the recipient. I have tried different approaches based on what I have read and looked at in sample formats. None worked within my NetBeans 8.2 IDE program. Seems there is always something that needs tweaking or changing. Very frustrating. If anyone could be so kind as to show me how I can add more files to the code below I would be forever grateful. I know this seems redundant with many other responses in this forum. However, after trying many responses, I get different error codes. This is my first attempt at using JavaMail and the am finding difficulty resolving the "multipart" section to accept 3 files.

```
public void sendEMAIL() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String attachFile1 = "C:\\Users\\wmelendez\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PlumbPRO\\Plumb- 
    13052021.docx";
    String attachFile2 = "C:\\Users\\wmelendez\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PlumbPRO\\Plumb- 
    13052021.xlsx";
    String attachFile3 = "C:\\Users\\wmelendez\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\PlumbPRO\\Plumb2- 
    13052021.xlsx";

    user = jtxtfld_USER.getText();
    emailPSWD = new String(this.jtxtfld_PASSWD1.getPassword());
    emailTO = jtxtfld_TO.getText();
    emailCC = jtxtfld_CC.getText();
    Date date = new Date();
    emailDATE = date.toString();
    emailFROM = jtxtfld_FROM.getText();
    emailBCC = "     ";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, emailPSWD);
        }
    });
    String Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", Host); //gmail host
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); //587,993
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
    props.setProperty("mail.user", user);
    props.setProperty("mail.password", emailPSWD);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    session.setDebug(true);

    try {
        String txtMSG = jtxtarea_MESSAGE.getText();

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTO));
        msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(emailCC));
        msg.setSubject("Report " + date + " ");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(txtMSG);

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(txtMSG, "text/html");
        MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart.setContent(txtMSG, "text/html");
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(attachFile1);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachFile1);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        msg.setContent(multipart);

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.connect(Host, 465, user, emailPSWD);
        transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Sent Ok");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What difference does the Java IDE make for this use case - which is really a Java Mail API question.

Comment: None. It was for some historical or background info. But you do have a point -I should not have included it. My bad -I tend to put too much info.

Comment: Have you tried to use AWS Simple Email Service to send email. It works nicely with Java and sending attachments.

Comment: No, I can't use AWS or any external server. Strictly desktop. I can send one email attachment, but really need to send 3 files (1 docx and 2 xlsx). Just can't figure out the multipart section (other than for one attachment). Any help would be appreciated.